# Loop with ArrayList received from Java Servlet as JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsp, servlets

This is my  jsp file code.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        debugger;
        </script>
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
                <c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />


                <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myList">
                    <tr>


                        <td>${myList}</td>
                    </tr>

                </c:forEach>
           </table>

        </body>


    </html>
```

The respone that i get after printing myList is

> [{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [71.2321239, 30.9569219]}, {"type":
>   "Point", "coordinates": [74.04084713, 31.27679252]}, {"type": "Point",
>   "coordinates": [73.1061811, 33.6336417]}]

it contains a total of 3 elements. when i print `myList.size()` it also shows me 3. Now i want to print all of these array element using a index number e.g. `myList[index]` with a for loop. How can i implement another for loop to print the elements of array using index number.

Comment: `<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myList">` here you are replacing (hiding) the list "myList" with a local var also named "myList" — name your _var_ something else, like "item" `<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item">` then `<td>${item}</td>`